# How to use remote with Kodi 17.6 in ArchLinux?

Tags: kodi, archlinux, input-device

I want to use all buttons of my remote control [picture](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/712A3jWV26L._SL1200_.jpg). Mainly the volume and the keyboard when entering text.

My system is Arch with Kodi 17.6 I assumed that the following post would fix it [here](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=203623). I added the file `appcommand.xmp` to `~/.kodi/userdata/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<keymap>
  <global>
    <appcommand>
      <browser_back>Back</browser_back>
      <browser_forward/>
      <browser_refresh/>
      <browser_stop>Stop</browser_stop>
      <browser_search>ActivateWindow(Favourites)</browser_search>
      <browser_favorites>ActivateWindow(Favourites)</browser_favorites>
      <browser_home>ActivateWindow(Home)</browser_home>
      <volume_mute>Mute</volume_mute>
      <volume_down>VolumeDown</volume_down>
      <volume_up>VolumeUp</volume_up>
      <next_track>SkipNext</next_track>
      <prev_track>SkipPrevious</prev_track>
      <stop>Stop</stop>
      <play_pause>PlayPause</play_pause>
      <launch_mail/>
      <launch_media_select>ActivateWindow(Videos,MovieTitles)</launch_media_select>
      <launch_app1>ActivateWindow(MyPrograms)</launch_app1>
      <launch_app2>ActivateWindow(MyPrograms)</launch_app2>
      <play>Play</play>
      <pause>Pause</pause>
      <fastforward>FastForward</fastforward>
      <rewind>Rewind</rewind>
      <channelup>PageUp</channelup>
      <channeldown>PageDown</channeldown>
    </appcommand>
  </global>
</keymap>
```

However without success. then I tried 
`evtest`

```
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Not running as root, no devices may be available.
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  MemsArt MA144 RF Controller
/dev/input/event1:  MemsArt MA144 RF Controller
/dev/input/event2:  MemsArt MA144 RF Controller
Select the device event number [0-2]: 0
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0xc45 product 0x5101 version 0x110
Input device name: "MemsArt MA144 RF Controller"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    Event code 4 (KEY_3)
    Event code 5 (KEY_4)
    Event code 6 (KEY_5)
    Event code 7 (KEY_6)
    Event code 8 (KEY_7)
    Event code 9 (KEY_8)
    Event code 10 (KEY_9)
    Event code 11 (KEY_0)
    Event code 12 (KEY_MINUS)
    Event code 13 (KEY_EQUAL)
    Event code 14 (KEY_BACKSPACE)
    Event code 15 (KEY_TAB)
    Event code 16 (KEY_Q)
    Event code 17 (KEY_W)
    Event code 18 (KEY_E)
    Event code 19 (KEY_R)
    Event code 20 (KEY_T)
    Event code 21 (KEY_Y)
    Event code 22 (KEY_U)
    Event code 23 (KEY_I)
    Event code 24 (KEY_O)
    Event code 25 (KEY_P)
    Event code 26 (KEY_LEFTBRACE)
    Event code 27 (KEY_RIGHTBRACE)
    Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
    Event code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL)
    Event code 30 (KEY_A)
    Event code 31 (KEY_S)
    Event code 32 (KEY_D)
    Event code 33 (KEY_F)
    Event code 34 (KEY_G)
    Event code 35 (KEY_H)
    Event code 36 (KEY_J)
    Event code 37 (KEY_K)
    Event code 38 (KEY_L)
    Event code 39 (KEY_SEMICOLON)
    Event code 40 (KEY_APOSTROPHE)
    Event code 41 (KEY_GRAVE)
    Event code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT)
    Event code 43 (KEY_BACKSLASH)
    Event code 44 (KEY_Z)
    Event code 45 (KEY_X)
    Event code 46 (KEY_C)
    Event code 47 (KEY_V)
    Event code 48 (KEY_B)
    Event code 49 (KEY_N)
    Event code 50 (KEY_M)
    Event code 51 (KEY_COMMA)
    Event code 52 (KEY_DOT)
    Event code 53 (KEY_SLASH)
    Event code 54 (KEY_RIGHTSHIFT)
    Event code 55 (KEY_KPASTERISK)
    Event code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT)
    Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
    Event code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK)
    Event code 59 (KEY_F1)
    Event code 60 (KEY_F2)
    Event code 61 (KEY_F3)
    Event code 62 (KEY_F4)
    Event code 63 (KEY_F5)
    Event code 64 (KEY_F6)
    Event code 65 (KEY_F7)
    Event code 66 (KEY_F8)
    Event code 67 (KEY_F9)
    Event code 68 (KEY_F10)
    Event code 69 (KEY_NUMLOCK)
    Event code 70 (KEY_SCROLLLOCK)
    Event code 71 (KEY_KP7)
    Event code 72 (KEY_KP8)
    Event code 73 (KEY_KP9)
    Event code 74 (KEY_KPMINUS)
    Event code 75 (KEY_KP4)
    Event code 76 (KEY_KP5)
    Event code 77 (KEY_KP6)
    Event code 78 (KEY_KPPLUS)
    Event code 79 (KEY_KP1)
    Event code 80 (KEY_KP2)
    Event code 81 (KEY_KP3)
    Event code 82 (KEY_KP0)
    Event code 83 (KEY_KPDOT)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    Event code 87 (KEY_F11)
    Event code 88 (KEY_F12)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    Event code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL)
    Event code 98 (KEY_KPSLASH)
    Event code 99 (KEY_SYSRQ)
    Event code 100 (KEY_RIGHTALT)
    Event code 102 (KEY_HOME)
    Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
    Event code 104 (KEY_PAGEUP)
    Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
    Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
    Event code 107 (KEY_END)
    Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
    Event code 109 (KEY_PAGEDOWN)
    Event code 110 (KEY_INSERT)
    Event code 111 (KEY_DELETE)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 117 (KEY_KPEQUAL)
    Event code 119 (KEY_PAUSE)
    Event code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA)
    Event code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA)
    Event code 127 (KEY_COMPOSE)
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 129 (KEY_AGAIN)
    Event code 130 (KEY_PROPS)
    Event code 131 (KEY_UNDO)
    Event code 132 (KEY_FRONT)
    Event code 133 (KEY_COPY)
    Event code 134 (KEY_OPEN)
    Event code 135 (KEY_PASTE)
    Event code 136 (KEY_FIND)
    Event code 137 (KEY_CUT)
    Event code 138 (KEY_HELP)
    Event code 183 (KEY_F13)
    Event code 184 (KEY_F14)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    Event code 186 (KEY_F16)
    Event code 187 (KEY_F17)
    Event code 188 (KEY_F18)
    Event code 189 (KEY_F19)
    Event code 190 (KEY_F20)
    Event code 191 (KEY_F21)
    Event code 192 (KEY_F22)
    Event code 193 (KEY_F23)
    Event code 194 (KEY_F24)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML) state 0
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL) state 0
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL) state 0
    Event code 3 (LED_COMPOSE) state 0
    Event code 4 (LED_KANA) state 0
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    400
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     80
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
***********************************************
  This device is grabbed by another process.
  No events are available to evtest while the
  other grab is active.
  In most cases, this is caused by an X driver,
  try VT-switching and re-run evtest again.
  Run the following command to see processes with
  an open fd on this device
 "fuser -v /dev/input/event0"
***********************************************
```

So I guess my remote is recognized as MemsArt MA144 RF Controller. but the command `fuser -v /dev/input/event0` returns nothing and still I am unsure how to fix the system and use the remote properly.

I expected that all the buttons work such as volume down and the keyboard when entering text. 
Currently volume up works and the keyboard on movie selection. More precisely when I press <kbd>c</kbd> on a file the pop up menu opens with "information" etc. when I on the movie selection.